# Theorem from Durrett's Probability: If $X_n$ is a supermartingale, then $X_n\wedge a$ is a supermartingale.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

This is Theorem 5.2.4 from Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples.

If $X_n$ is a submartingale with respect to $F_n$ and $\phi$ is an increasing convex function with $E|\phi(X_n)|<\infty$ for all $n$, then $\phi(X_n)$ is a submartingale with respect to $F_n$. Consequently (i) If $X_n$ is a submartingale, then $(X_n-a)^+$ is a submartingale. (ii) If $X_n$ is a supermartingale, then $X_n\wedge a$ is a supermartingale.

I don't understand how to get (ii) from the theorem. I think I should consider $-X_n$, thus getting a submartingale, but I can't think of a convex function, which after putting $-$ back I would get $X_n\wedge a$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Try $\phi(x)=x\vee(-a)$ applied to $Y_n=-X_n$. Or, write the process $X_n\wedge a$ as the sum of the supermartingales $X_n$ and $-(X_n-a)^+$.

Comment: @Did Can you explain why $-(X_n-a)^+$ is a supermartingale? From (i), we should have $-(-X_n-a)^+$ is a supermartingale, but how do we get $-(X_n-a)^+$ is a supermartingale?

Comment: My bad, one should use instead (i') If $X_n$ is a submartingale, then $(X_n-a)^-$ is a submartingale. Then, assume that $(X_n)$ is a supermartingale, hence $(X_n)$ is a submartingale hence $(-X_n+a)^-$ is a submartingale, that is, $(X_n-a)^+$ is a submartingale hence $-(X_n-a)^+$ is a supermartingale, as desired.

Comment: @Did Sorry but how do we get $(X_n-a)^+$ is a submartingale from the fact that $(-X_n+a)^-$ is a submartingale? $(X_n-a)^+=\frac{1}{2}(X_n-a+|X_n-a|)$ and $(-X_n+a)^-=\frac{1}{2}((-X_n+a)-|X_n-a|)$ but I don't see how to get one from the other.

Comment: No, $x^-=\max(-x,0)=\frac12(|x|-x)$. Remember that $$x^+-x^-=x\qquad x^++x^-=|x|$$

Comment: @Did oh right sorry I got confused. But then how do we get (i') in your second comment?

Comment: Just like (i) (by convexity).

Comment: @Did How can I show that $x^-$ is convex? I know that $x^+$ is convex because it is a sum of two convex functions $|x|$ and $x$. But $x^-$ is a sum of a convex and a concave function.

Comment: Actually, $x^-$ is also the sum of two convex functions...